# Passing data without textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, qr-code

I'm currently having an issue trying to pass data from a QR Code scanner controller to a view controller. The reason for doing this is because I'm gonna have 30+ Qr codes during an event, and all these codes will segue to the same view controller but with different label/data.

View Controller

```
var myString:String = ""
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label?.text = myString

}
```

QR Scanner Controller

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
let secondController = segue.destination as! Sample3Controller
  if segue.identifier == "Segue1"
       {
           secondController.myString = "Welcome to Booth 1"
       }
  else if segue.identifier == "Segue2"
       {
           secondController.myString = "Welcome to Booth 2"
       }
     }
            if metadataObj.stringValue == "Booth 1" //if qr code text is "Booth1"
            {
                captureSession?.stopRunning()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue1", sender: self)
            }
            else if metadataObj.stringValue == "Booth 2" // if qr code text is "Booth2"
            {
                captureSession?.stopRunning()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue2", sender: self)
            }
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: It can't work. my string doesn't display at all

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to archive. Why you are using different segues? Is the @IBOutlet correct connected?

Comment: Why call `performSegue ` inside `prepare(for segue)`?? Remove that part, not sure how your code work also

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs because i thght with different segues it will display different labels. For example if u see the QR Scanner controller, if the Segue identifier is "Segue1", it will display "Welcome to Booth 1" and or if its "Segue2", it will display "Welcome to Booth 2". So on and so forth.

Comment: @Tj3n but its not, the perform segue is not in the prepare(for segue) func

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the line `secondController.myString = ...` to see if it get called or not

Comment: @Kinja, this is the wrong approach. You only need one segue for this and pass the data to the view controller. Also Tj3n is right, the prepare is called just before the segue is already fired.

Comment: @Tj3n u're right it doesn't :/, there's a thread 1:breakpoint at the if metadataObj.Stringvalue == "Booth 5"

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs and what would be the correct approach to this? because i'm super new to Xcode and all these codes are from youtube video tutorials.

Comment: @Kinja https://stackoverflow.com/a/31934786/442121

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs but he's using it with a textfield and i'm not, would the logic still be the same?

Comment: @Kinja yes, it is still the same. You want to know how to pass data between view controllers the correct way.

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs bro i tried it, it still doesn't work under my QR code scanner logic

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs nevermind i managed to solved it using user defaults